# .NET ValidationSummary control not formatting inside UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, ajax, validation

I have some validation controls inside of an Update Panel in my ASP.NET page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server">
            <Triggers>  
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function ValidatorUpdateDisplay(val) {
                        if (typeof (val.display) == "string") {
                            if (val.display == "None") {
                                return;
                            }
                            if (val.display == "Dynamic") {
                                val.style.display = val.isvalid ? "none" : "inline";
                                return;
                            }

                        }
                        val.style.visibility = val.isvalid ? "hidden" : "visible";
                        if (val.isvalid) {
                            document.getElementById(val.controltovalidate).style.border = '1px solid #808080';
                        }
                        else {
                            document.getElementById(val.controltovalidate).style.border = '1px solid red';
                        }
                    }
                </script>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtName" CssClass="label" Text="Your Name: (required)" /><asp:TextBox ID="txtName" CssClass="singlelineTxt" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="ContactForm" runat="server" /><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtCompany" CssClass="label"  Text="Company: (optional)" /><asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" CssClass="singlelineTxt" runat="server" /><br/>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtEmail" CssClass="label"  Text="Your Email: (required)" /><asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" CssClass="singlelineTxt" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="ContactForm" runat="server" /><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtSubject" CssClass="label"  Text="Subject: (required)" /><asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" CssClass="singlelineTxt" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="ContactForm" runat="server"/><br />
                <div id="TextArea"><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtMessage" CssClass="label"  Text="Message: (required)" /><asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" CssClass="multilineTxt" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="ContactForm" TextMode="MultiLine" Wrap="true" runat="server" /></div><br />
                <div id="cbCaptcha" style="display: none;"><!-- for callback recaptcha reload --></div>
                <cc1:Recaptcha ID="Recaptcha1" CssClass="captcha" Theme="Clean" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="ContactForm" CssClass="button" runat="server" text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/><br /><br />
                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValSum1" CssClass="error" ForeColor="" DisplayMode="SingleParagraph" runat="server" />
                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" CssClass="messageSuccess" Visible="false" Text="SUCCESS" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqName" ErrorMessage="Name is required." ControlToValidate="txtName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactForm" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqEmail" ErrorMessage="Email is required." ControlToValidate="txtEmail" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactForm" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqSubj" ErrorMessage="Subject is required." ControlToValidate="txtSubject" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactForm" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqMsg" ErrorMessage="Message is required." ControlToValidate="txtMessage" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactForm" />
             </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And I have some very simple CSS to (attempt) to style it:

```
.error{
    border: 2px solid red;
    color: #f00;
}
```

However, no matter what I seem to try to do, I cannot get this Validation Summary to reflect any kind of styling what so ever. I have been doing research surrounding AJAX and how Update Panels work for a few hours now hoping to find something that would hint at the ROOT of the problem, revisited and revised and tinkered with the other style sheets... Nothing doing.

Does anyone have a clue what would prevent an ASP.NET Control with a CssClass property from rendering using the CssClass specified?

Comment: what type of styling do u want, did you tried giving `!important` to the attribute ?

Comment: The exact type of styling I want is indicated in the question. adding !important does nothing. It isn't the individual attribute that isn't being applied, it's none of the attributes in the CSS class. The only style it seems to be using is the very top level HTML font color and font size. It won't even render as a bulleted list, even if I tell it to.

Comment: I HAS to have something to do with the update panel. When I move the validation control outside of the update panel, it styles properly.

Comment: Can you paste your `update panel` code ?

Comment: remove your javascript code inside the update panel and check

Comment: I already tried that and it doesn't do anything. Are you just guessing?

Comment: No, might be in your js code there might be something blocking your style to work. Can you please paste your full code here http://jsfiddle.net/  section wise and give the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72734/discussion-between-taki-martillo-and-nadeem-khan).

Answer (score 0):

I guess some other thing is stopping from your `CSS` style to work. Because it working fine at my end.

Also what I found is, Inside your update panel. `Script Manager` is missing. Please add like below

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sc1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Have a [look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9i5w.png)

Comment: I'm not missing a script manager, I just didn't paste the entire .aspx page in my question.

Comment: @takiMartillo: But the validation thing is working on my side, can you try on new fresh page.?

Answer (score 0):

When using asp-validation-summary element I don't think that the generated HTML includes any additional classes specified in it's class statement. I got around this by adding an entry into my CSS style sheet:

```
.validation-summary-errors ul li {
    color: red !
}
```